# Find files in all directories by name in and copy to another directory using rsync

Tags: find, rsync, xargs

I have listed file names each per line in `list.txt` like below

```
filename1.pdf   
file456.pdf  
file33.txt  
.......
```

I want to search by file name in a directory (including all subfolders in source) and copy them to target directory (all in one directory)

```
rsync -a /var/www/html/source-directory  --files-from=/home/directory/list.txt /var/www/html/target-directory
```

This command working fine, but it search only source directory, but not inside folders.

Comment: Please help any command is fine like find, xargs, and including bash..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need `rsync` for this. For each file, you need to find it and then copy it to the destination

```
src='/var/www/html/source-directory'
dst='/var/www/html/target-directory'

while IFS= read -r file
do
    echo "Checking '$file'" >&2
    find "$src" -type f -name "$file" -exec cp -a {} "$dst/" \;
done <list.txt
```

If you can guarantee there's only one of each named file, some versions of `find` will have a `-quit` option that you can append, so that it stops on its first match of each file.

Comment: Did you create the file on Windows?

Comment: No, it's on ubuntu. when I put echo in loop it's reading line by line. No issues, but copying files is the problem.

Comment: Are the names in `list.txt` really just names or are they paths? Any extra whitespace? And this file really wasn't created in Windows. Try this in the loop `echo "Checking '$file'"`. Do you get a quoted filename eg `Checking 'filename1.pdf'`

Comment: Yes, only file name and no path. Also yes, spaces are there in file names. Tried printing above as mentioned, yes it's displayed like checking 'test.txt'
checking '20111012102310704734china and Israil.pdf'
checking '20111017105216305734kwait millions.pdf'

Comment: It's worked now, i just removed list.txt file and created new file with nano editor and added list, and ran your code, it's working fine. Thanks a lot for your help !!!